# What is the correct way of filtering the output of group_by with Range-v3?

Tags: c++, c++17, range-v3

The following code does not compile because `x` cannot be compared with a `std::vector<int>`, as `x` is a more complex structure handled by Range-v3 (which is good, because it's lazy, unlike `std::vector<int>`).

How can I write the filtering lambda to cope with that, possibly without forcing an unnecessary conversion of `x` to `std::vector<int>`?

```cpp
#include <range/v3/view/filter.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/group_by.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};
    auto w = v
        | ranges::views::group_by([](auto const& c1, auto const& c2){ return c1 == 3 && c2 == 4; })
        | ranges::views::filter([](auto const& x){ return x != std::vector<int>{3,4}; });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might still transform the view into vector:

```
 | ranges::views::filter([](auto const& x){ return (x | ranges::to_vector) != std::vector<int>{3,4}; });
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84295b8e293c691f)

or without converting to vector, use `ranges::equal`:

```
ranges::view::filter([](auto const& x){ return !ranges::equal(x, std::vector<int>{3,4}); })
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccd132ee8daddcc8)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but that's what I was looking for!